# $W(k)\langle p^{\frac{1}{p^{}\infty}}\rangle$ is a perfectoid valuation ring

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $W(k)$ be the Witt vector ring which k is a perfect field. $K^o:=W(k)\langle p^{\frac{1}{p^{\infty}}}\rangle$ is the competition of $\ \cup_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} W(k)[p^{\frac{1}{p^{i}}}]$. A paper says that $K^o$ is a perfectoid valuation ring, i.e. valuation ring of mixed char (0,p), non-discrete, and the Frobenius map $K^o/p^{\frac{1}{p}} \rightarrow K^o/p,\ x \mapsto x^p$ is surjective.

I know it is no-discrete since $p^{\frac{1}{p^{i}}}$ in the ring. But I don't know what is the valuation of $K^o$ and the relation with the valuation of $W(k)$ and what $K^o/p^{\frac{1}{p}}$ be like.

Further more, it seems that $A:=\cup_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} W(k)[p^{\frac{1}{p^{i}}}][[x_1^{\frac{1}{p^{i}}},...,x_n^{\frac{1}{p^{i}}}]]$ is perfectoid $K^o$-algebra. How to prove that?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you get with $k=\Bbb{F}_p$?

Comment: A formatting tip: Angle brackets $\langle \cdots \rangle$ are `\langle` and `\rangle`, as opposed to the less-than and greater-than signs `<` and `>` (which give very ugly spacing if used as brackets, since they are interpreted as relational symbols rather than delimiters).